# Why playframework stored image attachments with no extension?

Tags: java, playframework

I didn't change the configuration , but i found the uploaded images were stored with no extension. **This makes me confused when managing those images**.

Is there anyone knows how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Checkout this [article](http://www.lunatech-research.fr/playframework-file-upload-blob).
Especially the part about saving the file.

And secondly, when uploading, you're uploading files. Not images by default. And files do not have img extensions. That part has to be managed manually.

Comment: I have checked that article before,but it doesn't say anything about file extension, it just save files normally.

Comment: Read it again. `MimeTypes.getContentType(photo.getName())`